# Determine all $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(f(x) + y) = f(x^2 - y) + 4yf(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> Determine all $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $$f\big(f(x) + y\big) = f(x^2 - y) + 4yf(x)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

$f(x) = 0$ is obvious , but how can we find all other functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just want to make sure there are no typos.  Is your function equation $$f\big(f(x)+y\big)=f(x^2-y)+4{\color{red}y}\,f(x)$$ instead?

Comment: Yes , sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @Batominovski HOW DID YOU KNOW THAT!?

Comment: @user780985  The old version seems to have only $f(x)=0$ as a solution (this is only a guess).  The corrected version has a nontrivial solution $f(x)=x^2$.  Usually problem makers like problems with nontrivial solutions.

Comment: @Batominovski Colour me impressed then!

Comment: @Batominovski wow...

Comment: This is from the 1996 Iran TST, and [a solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1141874p5368220) is found on AOPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy
$$f\big(f(x) + y\big) = f(x^2 - y) + 4y\,f(x)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  By setting $y:=\dfrac{x^2-f(x)}{2}$ in the given functional equation, we get
$$\begin{align}f\left(\frac{x^2+f(x)}{2}\right)&=f\left(f(x)+\frac{x^2-f(x)}{2}\right)\\&=f\left(x^2-\frac{x^2-f(x)}{2}\right)+4\,\left(\frac{x^2-f(x)}{2}\right)\,f(x)\\&=f\left(\frac{x^2+f(x)}{2}\right)+4\,\left(\frac{x^2-f(x)}{2}\right)\,f(x)\end{align}$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore, $4\,\left(\dfrac{x^2-f(x)}{2}\right)\,f(x)=0$ for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Hence, we can conclude that, for each real number $x$, either
$$f(x)=0\text{ or }f(x)=x^2\,.\tag{*}$$
In particular, this means $f(0)=0$.

Suppose that there are two nonzero real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $f(s)=0$ and $f(t)=t^2$.  Then, by plugging in $x:=s$ and $y:=t$ in the given functional equation, we have
$$t^2=f(t)=f\big(f(s)+t\big)=f(s^2-t)+4t\,f(s)=f(s^2-t)\,.$$
By (*), $f(s^2-t)=0$ or $f(s^2-t)=(s^2-t)^2$.  Thus, either
$$t^2=0\text{ or }t^2=(s^2-t)^2\,.$$
This means $t=0$, $s=0$, or $s^2=2t$.  Since $s$ and $t$ are nonzero, we obtain
$$s^2=2t\,.\tag{#}$$
However, (#) holds for any values of $s\neq 0$ and $t\neq 0$ such that $f(s)=0$ and $f(t)=t^2$.  It can then be easily seen (why?) that, unless

- $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or
- $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

the equation (#) yields a contradiction.

---

I shall also solve the old (now changed) version.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy
$$f\big(f(x) + y\big) = f(x^2 - y) + 4x\,f(x)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  We proceed as before by setting $y:=\dfrac{x^2-f(x)}{2}$.  However, this time we get
$$4x\,f(x)=0$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Thus, if $x\neq 0$, then $f(x)=0$.  Now, by setting $x$ and $y$ to be $0$, we obtain
$$f\big(f(0)\big)=f(0)\,.$$
If $f(0)\neq 0$, then $f\big(f(0)\big)=0$, whence $f(0)=0$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $f(0)$ must be $0$, and so $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why it's easy seen?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:
$$P(x,y)\implies f(f(x)+y)=f(x^2−y)+4yf(x)$$
$$P(x,-f(x))\implies f(0)=f(x^2+f(x))-4f(x)^2 \iff f(x^2+f(x))=f(0)+4f(x)^2$$
$$P(x,x^2)\implies f(x^2+f(x))=f(0)+4x^2f(x)$$
Combining the above 2 statements:$$ \implies f(0)+4f(x)^2=f(0)+4x^2f(x) \iff f(x)^2=x^2f(x)$$
Putting $x=0$ we get that $f(0)=0$, and it gives two cases:

Case 1: $f(x)=0 \ \ \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$

Case 2: there exists a real number $a$ such that $f(a) \ne 0$

Then $$f(a)^2=a^2f(a) \implies f(a)=a^2$$
$$f(a) \ne 0 \implies a^2 \ne 0 \implies a \ne0$$
So $f(a)=a^2$ for all $a \ne 0$, this and the fact that $f(0)=0$ gives $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$

Checking back in the original equation, we get that both solutions work, the only solutions $\Box.$

Comment: I have a warning for you.  This solution is not complete.  If this problem were in a competition, I believe you would get a lot of point reduction.  So far, you have shown that, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x^2$.  This does not yet imply that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, or $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This is because $\forall x\big[P(x)\vee Q(x)\big]$ and $\Big(\forall x\big[P(x)\big]\Big)\vee \Big(\forall x\big[Q(x)\big]\Big)$ are not logically equivalent.  That is why I had to go through the trouble to derive Equation (#) in my answer.

Comment: Yes but I meant that in the solution that $f(x)=0 \forall x$ or $f(x)=x^2 \forall x$, because if $f(x) \ne 0$ we can divide by it and get our solution. Do I still get reduction points? I am not totally understanding, thanks for your help

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim You have shown that, for every $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = x^2$. This doesn't give you two choices of functions over $\Bbb{R}$, this gives you two choices of function value **for each $x$**. For example, if we had a solution such that $f(2) = 4$, this doesn't tell us whether $f(3) = 9$ or $f(3) = 0$, or whether $f(\pi) = \pi^2$ or $0$, etc. The function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x \in [-1, 1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ could be a third solution, based on your working, as it also satisfies $f(x)^2 = x^2 f(x)$ for each $x$.

Comment: It's like saying $xy=0$ means for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x=0$ or $y=0$, not $x=0$ or $x \ne 0 \implies y=0$. I still do not understand fully, more details or examples, please.

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim More examples? You got to the equation $f(x)^2 = x^2f(x)$ and claimed there were two solutions $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = 0$. I came up with, in the comment above, a **third** function $f(x)$ which satisfies the equation (but not the original functional equation). Can you see why the piecewise function satisfies $f(x)^2 = x^2f(x)$? Such a function still satisfies $f(x) = x^2$ or $f(x) = 0$ for any given $x \in \Bbb{R}$, but it is neither the quadratic function $x \mapsto x^2$, nor the constant function $x \mapsto 0$.

Comment: @Batominovski It came back to me that I had to go over this again, so I came back here again and I edited my answer. Is it OK now?

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim  No, you only proved in the second case that $f(a)\neq 0$ implies $a\neq 0$ and $f(a)=a^2$.  This is not equivalent to saying that $a\neq 0$ implies $f(a)\neq 0$ and $f(a)=a^2$.