# Functional equation $f(f(x)+y)=f(x^2-y)+4f(x)y$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(f(x)+y)=f(x^2-y)+4f(x)y, \forall x, y\in\mathbb{R}$$

By substitution $y\to\frac{x^2-f(x)}{2}$, $$f(x)(x^2-f(x))=0$$.
Now I want to prove that if there os some $x_0\neq0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, then $f(x)=0,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Substituting $x\to x_0$, $$f(x_0^2-y)=f(y)\implies f(x_0^2)=f(0)=0$$. Then by induction $f(x_0^{2^n})=0$. But I can't finish that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: solution https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1320755p7115333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine all $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(f(x) + y) = f(x^2 - y) + 4yf(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667515/determine-all-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-such-that-ffx-y-fx)